# create generic class to hold key value array (dictionary) with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, typescript-generics

i want to add Dictionary class for using in my app.
i created a class, and added an Array of keyValuePair to it, to hold my list

```
export class KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>{
key:TKey;
value:TVal;

constructor(key:TKey, val:TVal){
    this.key = key;
    this.value = val;
}

export class Dictionary<TKey, TVal>{
    array: Array<KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>>
}

let myClassInstance:Dictionary<number, string> = ...;
```

questions:

1. i want to be able to iterate it with forEach or in a loop as let x of myClassInstance how can i do this? (myClassInstance.forEach(...);)
2. can i use the class instance to get my array without calling className.arrayName?(myClassInstance.find(...);)
3. can I use the class instance as an index to get the values?(myClassInstance[1])

- if there is any better structure for this? i would like to hear and learn...
  thanks!!!

Comment: Since your keys are all numbers, which are valid object keys, why not just use a plain javascript object?  You would use the type Record<number, string> to describe it.

Comment: @LindaPaiste - is there anything i am loosing by using record rather than array?
i also don't know what is more efficient, as i will be using find on the array, is index better?
and do you have an implementation demo ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), they are dictionaries.

You can use them like this: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgeQMoBUD6BJOAFBAlFAQQDl0MARGAXhgEYBuAWACgXRJYBbATzgEMADtRhgApgHd4ggDxgArpwBGogE4AaGNBUBLMAHMAfAAoA2ixgwTABg0AiACaiAbqIA2IAatsBdNecuIqJg4+ESkmOR2ABai9nqiUSB6Pn7M3gCUTKzMPPwCAHQQolBGNjC2Ma7utpkwAPR1MCAuKjqOME58rnKiLLmChcVGAEx24iAqrvY1WewQIK6i+e56Rvnr-QWd3aIQRumZbODzi8tJaxu8AwDWotx7B1ksAGYTMEaLsNs9Tc8wm-lvrt9ukYABvfxzBZLFZGAAGSBAnFE4FEmj42nsMAAJGCgQBfOGHZj4lh9K4FV4qACifGAUSMRiBoKoBnB9UaAj4Kj4yKgqggAC4Ol0ehpbtwNJxBJDjtCzqs4VTafThbiCUSsvj0mTmFDTrC4RgYO4XDiwQD4iVAmQQgQSGRyOl8RBNUA).

You can iterate their values, keys or entries and they will be typed. You can find something using get. You can convert them to arrays [...myMap.values()], note: they will be ordered by the key insertion order. (you can use entries() instead and then map the result to sort by keys if needed)